# Duplicate Items in List from Network Api Call Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, duplicates

I have two fragments hosted in a tablayout, attached to an activity. In both, I'm making a network call to show data in recyclerview, successfully.

The problem lies when I open another activity from navigation drawer and go back to one of these fragments from the activity, the list is duplicated, another api call is made and more items are added to the list.

I have tried using `onStart, onStop and onDestroy` methods to clear the old items from the list like below:

```
public class SciFiFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = SciFiFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView scifiRV;

private List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
private ScifiWallpaperAdapter adapter;

private boolean hasItems = false;
private PixaImages pixaImages;

public SciFiFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View sv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sci_fi, container, false);

    scifiRV = sv.findViewById(R.id.scifiRV);
    scifiRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    scifiRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    if (Utils.isNetwork(getActivity())){
        fetchWallpapers();
    } else {
        // TODO: 6/12/2018 get from cache
        Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Check Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return sv;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    objectList.clear();
    objectList.remove(pixaImages);
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause---Size:\t" + objectList.size());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    objectList.clear();
    objectList.remove(pixaImages);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop---Size:\t" + objectList.size());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    objectList.clear();
    objectList.remove(pixaImages);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy---Size:\t" + objectList.size());
}

private void fetchWallpapers() {
    String url = Constants.PIXABAY_BASE_URL + "?key=" + Constants.PIX_API_KEY + "&q=nature&orientation=vertical&category=science";
    Log.d(TAG, "Scifi URL:\t" + url);
    AndroidNetworking.get(url)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .setTag("Get Scifi Wps")
            .getResponseOnlyIfCached()
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response != null){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Nature Wps Response:\t" + response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hits");
                            for (int m = 0; m < array.length(); m++){
                                JSONObject items = array.getJSONObject(m);

                                pixaImages = new PixaImages();
                                pixaImages.setImgId(items.getInt("id"));
                                pixaImages.setLargeImgURL(items.getString("largeImageURL"));
                                pixaImages.setPageURL(items.getString("pageURL"));
                                pixaImages.setPreviewImgURL(items.getString("previewURL"));

                                objectList.add(pixaImages);
                                Log.d(TAG, "List size:\t" + objectList.size());
                                adapter = new ScifiWallpaperAdapter(getActivity(), objectList);
                                scifiRV.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failure NATURE Wps:\t" + anError.getMessage().toString());
                }
            });
}

}
```

This works only when I exit the app, to open another app or recent apps screen but when I open another activity in same app, the list duplicates. How do I determine when to make the network call, can it be done periodically `w/o duplicates`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea I think is not to clear the previous data rather I'll suggest you maintain the state of the activity with the API calls by using `startActivityForResult` to lunch the next activity,

Or you can remove the activity that makes the calls from the back stack and use an intent to launch it each time.

Also in the Recycler view Adapter `notifyDatasetChanged` is a very helpful method to help the adapter know when the data has changed.

Comment: I have fixed this by restarting the tabbed activity and no more duplicates. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the list before adding items instead of clearing it on onPause or onResume
also, you don't need to create and set the adapter each time, do it once on start
and create a method in your adapter, some like this:

```
public void setWallpapers(List objects) { 
    if(this.objectsInAdapter == null) {
      this.objectInAdapter = new List<>();
   }
   this.objectsInAdapter.clear();
   this.objectsInAdapter = objects;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now, keep in mind that your approach will dump all info every time, you might want to add a mechanism to request only the objects you don't already have.